# How to upload multiple files in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

All the scripts I have found via Google search rely on some sort of screen that first asks the user how many files they need to upload and the upload script works based on that number.

But what if I don't want any limits, but want to allow the user to upload as many or as few as they want. How to go about this?

All I have for now is the form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="script.php">
 <input id="my_file_element" type="file" name="myFile[]" >
        <input type="submit" value="Upload!" name="submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

I think the way I phrased my question is causing some misunderstanding. I am not in need of some way to add more "input type = file" field elements. I am already using a javascript that enables the user to add more form fields by clicking a button, those other fields are identical to the 1st one posted above.

What I am asking this question for, is to know how to handle the actual upload of files to the server using a php script.

Comment: Use javascript, Luke. Adding HTML fields to HTML form is HTML and javascript's job. Not PHP.

Comment: Sorry, when I pressed "edit", you'd already edited the question. I sort of rolled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Let's say your form is like this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="script.php">
 <input id="my_file_element" type="file" name="myFile[]" >
 <input id="my_file_element" type="file" name="myFile[]" >
 <input id="my_file_element" type="file" name="myFile[]" >
 etc...
<input type="submit" value="Upload!" name="submit">
</form>
```

What you want to do is get all the files called `myFile[]`. Here's what you do in PHP:

```
foreach ($_FILES["myFile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
 if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   $tmp_name = $_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
   $name = $_FILES["myFile"]["name"][$key];
   // here we move it to a directory called data
   // you can move it wherever you want
   move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");
 } else {
   // an error occurred, handle it here
 }
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

Using HTML and JavaScript alone, there isn't any easy way to upload multiple files at the same time.

I would use a Flash library, such as [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/), to do the upload instead. Using this plugin, you can show a standard multi-file upload window, as shown in [this demo](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/formsdemo/index.php). This will allow users to easily select multiple files in the same file browser.

If you don't want to use Flash for some reason, you could use JavaScript to dynamically swap input elements, as in [this example](http://the-stickman.com/files/mootools/multiupload/).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

That depends on how you called the file `input` elements. If you followed my approach below, you can get the number of files with:

```
if (empty($_FILES['attach']['name']))
    $count_files = 0;
else
    $count_files = count($_FILES['attach']['name']);
```

Try `var_dump($_FILES)` to see the complete `$_FILES` array, in case you have any doubts on its structure.

**ORIGINAL**

Something like this, with Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j = 2; //default two files
function novoa() {
    j = j+1;
    var elem = document.createElement("input");
    var par = document.getElementById("filed");
    elem.setAttribute("type", "file");
    elem.name = "attach[]";
    elem.id = "file_" + j;
    par.appendChild(elem);
}
function delult() {
    if (j == 0) return;
    var elem = document.getElementById("file_" + j);
    var par = document.getElementById("filed");
    j = j-1;
    par.removeChild(elem);
}
</script>
...
<p id="addupl"><a href="javascript:novoa()">More files</a> |
    <a href="javascript:delult()">Less files</a></p>
<p id="filed">
<input type="file" name="attach[]" id="file_1" />
<input type="file" name="attach[]" id="file_2" />
</p>
```

Comment: sorry for you having to go through all that trouble, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

OMG you're asking how to handle this form?
there is an example **right on the manual page:**
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

```
<?php
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP script, do a `var_dump($_FILES)`. The output should help you move further into the direction you wish. Take a look at PHP's [filesystem functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) for more info on what you can do with the files, after using the `move_uploaded_file` function.

In order to really answer your question *How to handle the upload*, you'd need to tell us what you want to accomplish/do with the files.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JavaScript to append another input element to the form.